# Why is the div not getting returned when the condition is met in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the render() method of a class component as shown below.

```
render() {
    const dish = this.props.dish;
    if (dish != null) {
      return (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            <Card>
              <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </div>
          <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            { this.renderComments(dish) }
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }
```

Each dish consists of a list of comments. The renderComments() method is shown below.

```
 renderComments(dish) {
        dish.comments.map((comment) => {
            if(comment != null) {
                console.log(comment);
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h4>Comments</h4>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            else{
                return (
                    <div></div>
                );
            }
        })
  }
```

The `comment != null` condition is met and the console log is working, but the h4 element inside the div is not getting returned. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your renderComments method is not returning anything that why div is not rendering

Comment: TRy `return dish.comments.map((comment).....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return from your renderComments function:-

Try:-

```
renderComments(dish) {
  return dish.comments.map((comment) => {
    // rest of your code here
  })
}
```